# Assigning values to 2D matrices

Tags: c

I need to work on 2D matrices but after some assignment everything goes wrong. It's basically instructions.

Here's the code:

```
int matA[1][1], matB[1][7], matRes[1][7];
    memset (matA, 0, sizeof (matA));
    memset (matB, 0, sizeof (matB));
    memset (matRes, 0, sizeof (matRes));
      printf("test0 :%d \n",matB[1][0]);
    //matrice de fonction
    matB[1][0]= 0;
      printf("test1 :%d \n",matB[1][0]);
    matB[1][1]= matB[0][2]= matB[0][3]= 0;
      printf("test2 :%d \n",matB[1][0]);
    matB[0][0]= matB[0][4]= matB[0][6]= matB[1][2]= matB[1][4]= matB[1][5]= 1;
      printf("test3 :%d \n",matB[1][0]);
    matB[0][1]= matB[0][5]= matB[0][7]= matB[1][3]= matB[1][6]= matB[1][7]= -1;
      printf("test4 :%d \n",matB[1][0]);
    //matrice d'entrée
    matA[0][1]= matA[1][0] = 0;
      printf("test5 :%d \n",matB[1][0]);
    matA[0][0]= X;
      printf("test6 :%d \n",matB[1][0]);
    matA[1][1]= Y;
      printf("test7 :%d \n",matB[1][0]);
```

And the output:

```
test0 :0
test1 :0
test2 :0
test3 :0
test4 :-1
test5 :-1
test6 :3
test7 :3
```

Note that X and Y are 2 parameters to the function.

Comment: correct title of question.

Comment: `int matA[1][1]` is a 1 by 1 matrix. Is that what you really want?

Comment: tab are initialized at 0 no ? matA = [0][0]  [0][1]
                                     [1][0]  [1][1]

Comment: C hasn't gone crazy. You're writing beyond the bounds of your variable, into other memory locations. Size your arrays larger, and remember if you size an array as `int a[3];` you may only legally access indexes 0, 1, and 2... accessing index 3 is beyond the array.

Comment: Oh thanks math ! >< my eyes are not in places !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int matB[1][7];
matB[1][0]= 0;
```

This is not a valid index into `matB`. It probably overlaps with the memory used for `matA` or `matRes`. That's why changing  `matA` changes `matB[1][0]`.

Comment: oh ok i'm going to learn how i could solve this problem.. thanks i know in wich way i've to look !